# How can I get the name of the project containing the current sub-project?

Tags: cmake, project

With `cmake`, in a `CMakeLists.txt` file I can get the the name of the root project with `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME`, and the name of the current subproject with `PROJECT_NAME`.

Is there a way to get the name of the project at the level immediately above the current one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the `PROJECT_NAME` *before* the `project()` call in the current scope, which will give you the project name of the **parent scope**:

```
# Gives the project name of the parent scope.
message(${PROJECT_NAME})

# Define the project name for the current scope.
project(MyInnerProj)

# Now, gives the project name of the current scope: 'MyInnerProj'.
message(${PROJECT_NAME})
```